# I have the shared link of google drive pdf using that i have to download that pdf using angular7. Please tell me how to do it

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

i have the shared link of google drive pdf using that i have to download the pdf file using angular 7 . Athentication and api call i have done already . I want help on download part as i mention above .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: `<a [href]="url"  targe="_blank" > download</a>`  will do the basic download , you could also go for soulution mentioned in the comment before

Comment: will it work for google drive pdf ?

Comment: <a [href]="url" targe=""  download> download</a>